# Is oneboxing for Google+ posts coming to the chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat

[Oneboxing](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#formatting) is one of the brilliantly useful features of our chat system. Could we also have oneboxing for Google+ posts and profiles? I'm told it's the future.

Comment: This won't be implemented until at the very least the Google+ API is released.

Comment: Okay, this may now be considered.

Comment: Sounds reasonable...

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117453/onebox-google-posts-in-chat